# How to check is there any background color on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Following method use to set background color to canvas and I use fabricJS.

```
canvas.setBackgroundColor(event.color.toHex());
```

before going to next step, I need to check is there any background color on my canvas. How I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if(canvas.backgroundColor){
     alert(canvas.backgroundColor);
}
```